# Importing CSV file (Georeferenced with Google Earth) into ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-earth-pro

I had a CSV file that I just georeferenced using Google Earth's import feature. The CSV file contains information about businesses in the United States, such as the business' name, address, and description.

After georeferencing the data in Google Earth, Google Earth displays several points on the globe. When I click on each point, a pop up window appears that displays all of the information for the business in that location, such as the business' name, description, etc.

I would like to add that data into ArcMap, so that I have a shapefile that includes all of the attribute data in the CSV file. I right clicked on the folder that contains all of the point data in Google Earth, clicked "Save Place As". After doing so, Google earth created a `.kmz` file.

How do I import that `.kmz` file into ArcMap? When I tried to import the data using the conversion tools menu in ArcToolbox, the points all appeared in the correct locations, but the points weren't associated with any of the data in the CSV file (e.g. the business names and descriptions).

What am I doing wrong? I used Google Earth to georeference the data because it's free.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a sample of your CSV data (and perhaps a screenshot of what you see in Google Earth).

Comment: Does the output have a `.kml` suffix?

Comment: @Vince no, it had a `.kmz` suffix.

Comment: That is an ***extremely*** important point. Please [EDIT] the question to mention that.  Please also take the [Tour], which explains how details requested in comments should be used to improve the question.

Comment: @Midavalo unfortunately, I can't post the data here, but I edited the question to give a more detailed description of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may add csv data to arcmap as table and then join it to shapefile you created out of the *kmz* if getting attribute data remains the issue. You should have a common field in shp and csv to do this.

To perform table join right click your shp in table of contents and select join. Select the csv table you added and the common field in both tables.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to give more details about *how* to do this